# How to copy DB file from raw folder to project database in android programmatically

Tags: android, android-database

I have offlinedictionary.db that contains all the tables and information I need for my android app
I kept that db file in my raw folder and used below logic to copy the db to my project database path.

DbHelper.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.android.db.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class DbHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH;

    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
    private final Context mContext;

    private static int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private static String FIRST_DB_PATH;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "offlinedictionary.db";

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "DBHelper";


    public DbHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 4.2) {
            DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";

        } else {
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        }
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"database path: "+DB_PATH);

        mContext = context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        // If database not exists copy it from the assets

        boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"createDataBase: mDataBaseExist "+mDataBaseExist);

        if (!mDataBaseExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.close();
            try {
                // Copy the database from assests
                copyDataBase();
                Log.e("DataBaseHelper", "createDatabase database created");
            } catch (IOException mIOException) {
                throw new Error("Error Copying DataBase");
            }
        }

    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME);
        //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"checkDataBase: dbFile "+dbFile);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"checkDataBase: dbFile.exists() "+dbFile.exists());
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {


        InputStream mInput = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.offlinedictionary);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH;
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"copyDataBase: mInput "+mInput);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"copyDataBase: outFileName "+outFileName);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"copyDataBase: mOutput "+mOutput);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0) {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        FIRST_DB_PATH = mContext.getDatabasePath("offlinedictionary").toString();

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try {

            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Create Database");
            createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


     
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

I have added some logs :

```
2020-08-25 09:49:32.145 9432-9432/? D/DBHelper: database path: /data/user/0/com.android.db/databases/
2020-08-25 09:49:32.635 9432-9432/? D/DBHelper: database path: /data/user/0/com.android.db/databases/
2020-08-25 09:49:32.683 9432-9432/? D/DBHelper: Create Database
2020-08-25 09:49:32.684 9432-9432/? D/DBHelper: checkDataBase: dbFile /data/user/0/com.android.db/databases/offlinedictionary.db
2020-08-25 09:49:32.684 9432-9432/? D/DBHelper: checkDataBase: dbFile.exists() true
2020-08-25 09:49:32.684 9432-9432/? D/DBHelper: createDataBase: mDataBaseExist true
```

Now in the above logs it shows that DB file is present in the project database path, and offlinedictionary.db gets created.
But my DB file from raw folder do not gets copied.

Is there something wrong in the logic above?

Comment: Yes. copyDataBase is not called. You coded it like that.

Comment: `private void copyDataBase()` Wrong to place that function in a SQLiteOpenHelper class. Make it static or move it to your activity so you can call it directly from you activity. After calling it and succesfull copy reboot your device.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above comments (which I agree with), you miss the file name in

```
    String outFileName = DB_PATH;
    OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
```

in copyDataBase() method. DB_PATH contains only path to the database directory. It should look like:

```
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + file_name;
    OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
```